# HTML2HAML command not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I have installed the gems `"haml"` and `"haml-rails"`. Now i want to convert my erb files to haml with that command:

```
find . -name '*erb' | \
xargs ruby -e 'ARGV.each { |i| puts "html2haml -r #{i} #{i.sub(/erb$/,"haml")}"}' | \
bash
```

but it throws this error:

html2haml: command not found

What am I missing?

Comment: also check that the directory where gem executables are going is in your path. can't remember how to do that off the top of my head

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`html2haml` was moved from the `haml` gem into its own gem.

You can find more info about it here:

https://github.com/haml/html2haml